# Why Statements has only getter and can't be set through the only constructor in Saml2Assertion?

Tags: c#, saml, saml-2.0, assertion

I need to set statements like attribute or authentication ones in SAML assertion but `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2Assertion` doesn't allow to set `Statements` property neither via setter nor via the only constructor. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `.Statements` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.saml2assertion.statements?view=netframework-4.8.1) exposes a collection-type:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public Collection<Saml2Statement> Statements { get; }
```

[In the .NET world, collection-properties should always be implemented as `get`-only (aka *readonly*) properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227). **But the collection itself is still mutable**.

This rule is important, because it prevents whole classes of bugs caused by  unexpected object reference changes (c.f. naive replaceable `ObservableCollection<T>` view-model references in WPF... <sub>yeah, I've been there too...</sub>).

---

To add new statements, use the `.Add` method, or your friendly local `.AddRange` extension-method:

```
Saml2Assertion              s2a          = ...
IEnumerable<Saml2Statement> s2Statements = ...

s2a.Statements.AddRange( s2Statements );
```